new hiveCof() init error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf"
I encountered an exception while using Flink to write the Paimon table with hive catalog.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.initialize(HiveConf.java:4051)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<init>(HiveConf.java:4019)
    at org.apache.paimon.hive.HiveCatalog.createHiveConf(HiveCatalog.java:697)
    at org.apache.paimon.hive.HiveCatalog.createHiveConf(HiveCatalog.java:756)
    at org.apache.paimon.hive.HiveCatalog.createHiveCatalog(HiveCatalog.java:710)
    at org.apache.paimon.hive.HiveCatalogFactory.create(HiveCatalogFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.paimon.catalog.CatalogFactory.createCatalog(CatalogFactory.java:76)
    at org.apache.paimon.flink.FlinkCatalogFactory.createCatalog(FlinkCatalogFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.paimon.flink.FlinkCatalogFactory.createCatalog(FlinkCatalogFactory.java:59)
    at org.apache.paimon.flink.FlinkCatalogFactory.createCatalog(FlinkCatalogFactory.java:32)
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createCatalog(FactoryUtil.java:488)

The direct cause of the problem is that Hive's dependencies are stored in the Flink JVM classpath,  Hadoop's dependencies are stored in the pipeline.classpaths path.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf loaded by AppLadLoader, while org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf needs to be loaded by FlinkUserCodeClassLoader
========================================================================================
The parent of FlinkUserCodeClassLoader is AppClassLoader.so I add the code before init HiveConf, I thought that HiveConf and JobConf should be able to be found correctly,but in reality, I still encountered the same exception.
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(flinkUserCodeClassLoader);

The storage location of Hadoop and Flink dependencies cannot be easily changed, and it is necessary to ensure the compatibility of Flink jobs in the production environment.
Can someone familiar with the principle of classloader help point out how to solve this problem?

if you are using Intellij Idea go to Edit Configuration->Application settings and add the option Add dependencies with provided scope to the classpath so it may get fixed.
